# How to disable and get name for control in FlowLayoutPanel from ContextMenuStrip in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

My program contains buttons in a `FlowLayoutPanel`.
I want to disable any button when right click on it and click "Disable" in the `ContextMenuStrip`.

My code is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To 30
            Dim btn As New Button
            btn.Name = i
            btn.Text = i
            btn.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Use the ContextMenuStrip.Opening event.  When it fires your event handler can use the ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl property to find out which button was right-clicked.  Store it in a variable.  Do note the drastic flaw in the UI design, once you set the button's Enabled property to False you cannot right-click it again to re-enable it.  You'll have to re-think that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a public varibale for keeping a control

```
    public ctrl as button = nothing
```

you can create a right click by putting this code on mouse down...

```
If e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then Return
        Dim cms = New ContextMenuStrip

        ctrl = sender

        Dim item1 = cms.Items.Add("Disable")
        item1.Tag = 1
        AddHandler item1.Click, AddressOf Disable
end if
```

and in the diable sub you can code like this...

```
Private Sub Disable()
    ctrl.enabled = false
End Sub
```